# Compare values of two columns excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to compare two columns data in excel 2016 and i need to find the different rows of both columns.

In both columns certain row will be the same, but the idea is to get the different.

I saw some formulas with IF and COUNTIF, but is raises error trying to use. Any idea of the correct formula?

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "")
```

Comment: There's no way to tell you what's the problem with your current formula if you don't show it, please edit your question so we can see it.

Comment: I have two columns and when i insert the =IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "") it raises the error to fix the formula

Comment: Your formula looks fine to me. Just make sure you aren't writing that formula in Cell `A2` or anywhere in Column `B` as that will cause a circule reference. Paste that formula, as-is, into Cell `C2`. I just did and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried your formula and it works fine, try replacing , with ;

Comment: https://ibb.co/ch62oU

Comment: There is more than one "," @AndréBastos ;)

Comment: yes, you're right!